# FInding Exact Circumference and Exact Area of a Circle

Tags: area

My teacher gave us a question with the diameter being equal to 8 inches, the radius is equal to 4 inches, and the approximate circumference being equal to 25.12 inches. When he says to find the approximate area he says to use 3.14 for pi but I get the same answer using the pi sign and 3.14. However I cannot find the exact circumference when I know the approximate circumference and I am having trouble finding the area of the circle (both approximate and exact). Please help me? I'm pretty sure this should be easy but I am utterly confused.

[The Problem I Should Know](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n0gB4.png)

Comment: What formulae did you use for circumference and area?

$$\text{Circumference} = \pi\times\text{diameter} =2\pi\times \text{radius}\\
\text{Area} = \pi \times\left(\text{radius}\right)^2$$

Comment: Replying to peterwhy Yes. I used that formula for both but it didn't work.

Comment: One question at a time: what steps would you take to calculate the exact circumference, when the diameter and the radius are given? What $\pi$ value do you use for exact calculations?

Comment: @peterwhy I use the pi symbol as he says but it still won't calculate. I think the answer would be 12.56 but it says it's wrong.

Comment: $12.56$ is $3.14\times 4$ or about $\pi\times 4$, and $4$ inches is the radius. If we are still talking about circumference here, the formula should be

$$\text{Circumference} = \pi\times\text{diameter} =2\pi\times \text{radius}$$

Comment: So 3.14 times 8 = 25.12 but that's the approximate so what's the exact?

Comment: I think you mention in another question that you use a calculator? Try calculating $\pi\times 8$ for a more precise value?

Comment: The only problem is that my calculator still says the right answer but I will try again. pi times 8 equals 25.1327412287 inches correct?

Comment: Nevermind. I figured this out.